# Does Web API officially support more than one "Route" attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am looking to have two different routes map to the same action. I noticed the following works, but is it safe to do (i.e. was Web API written to support this kind of behaviour)?

```
[Route( "foo" )]
[Route( "bar" )]
public async Task<string> GetStuff()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is hard to tell whether it is *officially* supported. But if you have look at the [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) of the `RouteAttribute`, you see that the `AllowMultiple` property of the `AttributeUsage` attribute is set to true. This [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.allowmultiple(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to make sure that only one instance of an attribute can be used on the same target. The default value is `false`, so the developers  opted to explicitly allow multiple instances.

Therefore, I wouldn't hesitate to use it multiple times.